# No, I swear this isn't another regular rebus... introducing REBI RULES!

Tags: pattern, rebus

[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
[image]

These rebuses (rebi) require you to figure out what the phrase is saying. However, all the rebi follow a common rule they follow in which YOU have to solve for. They also follow a common theme, which is another thing YOU have to solve for.

Have fun!

edit:

> Also a freebie, the first rebus is supposed to have the word "of" in there somewhere. I forgot to add a clue for it (yikes!)

Comment: I haven't been on Puzzling SE for a while, so feedback is always appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Also sorry if these are too easy

Comment: You can also call these reb-eye sandwhich heh heh heh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial for image #1:

> com + $e$ + ? + ? = **come + ?**
>  [Muse](http://disneyshercules.wikia.com/wiki/The_Muses) - E4 + I + $c$ = **music**

Answer for Image #2 (thanks to help from the comments):

> Bible is actually a trilogy

Because:

- > bib + le (French "the") = Bible
- > [Isaac](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sacrifice_of_Isaac_by_A.Losenko.jpg) - A(cceleration) = is ac
- > 3 ⋅ [Tualatin](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Gallery:Tualatin) = first three letters = tua
- > [Eli Lilly and Co](https://www.lilly.com/): stock symbol **LLY**
- > at = a + t
- > [RIL](http://www.ril.com/) + [OG](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OG) + y

What I have above is "on the right path". Here's what else I've come up with

For image #1, could the book represent this?

> To me

I want to say the image to the right of that is this, (but I'm pretty sure it's wrong):

> Wings of an angle [sic]

Comment: Nice! I think the #2 says rot13[Ovoyr vf npghnyyl n gevybtl (ylevpf sebz "Nyy-Nzrevpna Cebcurg")]

Comment: Okay, rebi was just a word I made up lol. Don't worry about it. You're on the right path, all your guesses are correct!

Comment: - f/m  could be Force/Mass = Acceleration (a).  Also notice the 3 by the yugioh card.

Comment: The comments are actually really helpful. Just saying.

Comment: The comments are all right, btw. You should use them.

Comment: @North Well having the pieces in the right order is also a big help :P . Did I get #2?

Comment: Close, except, it's just isac, not ac

Comment: You get rid of one a, not isa

Comment: Besides that, you got it though!

Comment: for a hint for number one, find a direct synonym to a book

Answer (score 4):

#1 says

> Come to me, angel of music

which is

> from the lyrics of "Angel of Music" in the musical *The Phantom of the Opera*.

Explanation:

> www.blank.**com**
>  2.71828 = **e**
>  a book is a **tome**
>  wings over an angle = **angel**
>  missing from the rebus, but given in a comment: **of**
>  muses from Disney's *Hercules* minus E (musical note of 329.628 Hz) = **mus**
>  pointing to self = **i**
>  299792458 m/s is the speed of light, or **c**.

Laurel solved #2:

> Bible is actually a trilogy

which is

> from the lyrics of "All-American Prophet" in the musical *The Book of Mormon*.

So the theme is

> musicals, but I'm unsure what the common rule could be.

Comment: Nice job! I have no idea who to give the checkmark to, you guys both did about the same amount of work :\ Forget about the rules, since um (in retrospect they were a bad idea).

Comment: I'm going to give the checkmark to Laurel, since they answered first.

Comment: Great job though.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

2.71828

> equivalent to **e**, mathematical constant

329.628:

> **E**4 is about 329.628 Hz

299792458:

> equivalent to **c**, light of speed

original gangster:

> **kkk**? NO from OP in comment

why:

> **y** (homophone)

Comment: NOO original gangster is not KKK